# Guzzle Get Request but method undefined

Tags: php, guzzle

I am new to Guzzle (7.0). And i want to get the data of the request URL, checked the URL, works but my code returns with a 500 message. Is Guzzle installed correctly or is that the problem?

```
<?php
        require "vendor/autoload.php";
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://reqres.in']);
  
        $response = $client->request('GET', '/api/users', [
            'query' => [
            'page' => '2'
            ]
        ]);
 
    //get status code using $response->getStatusCode();
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $status = $response->getStatusCode();
    echo $status;
    $arr_body = json_decode($body);
    print_r($arr_body);
    ?>
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "jd/guzzle",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "email": "email"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~7"
    }
}
```

This is my server error.log:

```
[Mon Sep 21 09:30:23.493946 2020] [php7:error] [pid 9951] [client $IP-adress] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\\Client::request() in /var/www/html/guzzlehttp/index.php:18\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown  in /var/www/html/guzzlehttp/index.php on line 18
```

If you want more information just leave a comment, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your code, **it is with your Guzzle installation**.

The `Get` request to this url `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2` gives the same result in code and by manually making a request in the browser.

This is how my `composer.json` file looks like

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0"
    }
}
```

I installed Guzzle with composer `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`, you should probably re-install it.

Comment: Tried to reinstall, and reuploaded my script. Worked! Thank you very much!